# Data Extension Lookup returns nothing

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup, dataextensions

I have a DE called content with the following 2 columns - **language | text**

I need it to return the text from the text column when the language is en

This is what I have, It validates and runs but does not return anything.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

```
%%[ 


var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue 
set @lookupValue = "en" 
set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("content", "text", "Language", @en) 


]%% 
DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%
```

Answer (score 0):

A Lookup allows you to pull over a single value from a data extension, since you'll need both values you will want to do a LookupRows and then pull the values out of the row.

```
Set @rows = LookupRows("content","Language",@lookupValue)
Set @row = Row(@rows,1)
Set @language = field(@row,"language")
Set @text = field(@row,"text")
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution but get this error when I try to preview. 

Unable to generate preview
Invalid index (parameter 2) passed to Row function. Index must be less than or equal to the row count.
Index Value: 1
Row Count: 0
Function: Row(@rows,1)

Comment: That error indicates it can't find the row or the column name from the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

You had it looking up @EN but that variable wasn't set.
Try this:

```
%%[ 
     var @DEColumn1, @lookupValue  
     set @lookupValue = "en"  
     set @DEColumn1 = Lookup("content", "text", "Language", @lookupValue) 
]%%
```

> DEColumn1 is %%=v(@DEColumn1)=%%

Comment: Thanks, I tried. but again it returns absolutely nothing.

I double checked my segment, there is data, 

There's no errors

but it just does not return any data. :(

Comment: Cancel

I got it to work. I was trying to merge in html and it was returning nothing.

I cleared my DE and imported text and it works.

so.. is there anyway I can import html from a DE into my template?
I don't want to use content areas, but rather have this in a DE